# Delete Emails older than X days in Exchange 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange, exchange-2003

How can I delete emails for a specific email account older than X days in Exchange 2003 from the server?  I would like to do this from the server, not from the outlook client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the tool ExMerge. Here is a decription how to delete messages on the server using that utility:

[How do I use EXMERGE to delete specific messages from Exchange 2000/2003 mailboxes?](https://www.petri.co.il/delete_messages_from_mailboxes_by_using_exmerge.htm)

You can [download Exmerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=429163ec-dcdf-47dc-96da-1c12d67327d5&displaylang=en) in Microsoft's Download area.

Here is a screenshot of the selection criteria (by date):

[image]
<sub>(source: [petri.co.il](https://www.petri.co.il/images/exmerge_del16.gif))</sub>

Comment: this will do the trick once, or when run repeatedly. DLux's idea is better because once the Mailbox Manager policies are set, they will keep the database free of old mail.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Mailbox Manager Settings in the Recipient Policies to set a retention limit on email messages.

You can read the steps on how to accomplish this in [KB319188](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319188).